# Microsoft Access sort by aggregate?

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

Is there a way to sort by number of open tasks?

```
SELECT Tasks.ClientName, Count(*) AS OpenTaskCount
FROM Tasks
WHERE (((Tasks.Completed)=False))
GROUP BY Tasks.ClientName
ORDER BY OpenTaskCount DESC;
```

When I try this, it prompts for OpenTaskCount in the GUI.

Comment: Have you tried ORDER BY Count(*) DESC?

Comment: That did it! Now if you will make your reply an answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```sql
SELECT Tasks.ClientName, Count(*) AS OpenTaskCount
FROM Tasks
WHERE (((Tasks.Completed)=False))
GROUP BY Tasks.ClientName
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC;
```

Answer (score 2):

Either:

```
SELECT Tasks.ClientName, Count(*) AS OpenTaskCount
FROM Tasks
WHERE (((Tasks.Completed)=False))
GROUP BY Tasks.ClientName
ORDER BY Count(*) DESC;
```

or

```
SELECT Tasks.ClientName, Count(*) AS OpenTaskCount
FROM Tasks
WHERE (((Tasks.Completed)=False))
GROUP BY Tasks.ClientName
ORDER BY 2 DESC;
```

should work.